# Laravel schedular works manually but not automatically?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, scheduled-tasks, cron-task

I have this in my `Kernal.php`:

```
$schedule->call('removeTemporaryFiles')->everyMinute();
```

When I hit `php artisan schedule:run` it works like charm. But I also ran:

```
 * * * * * php /var/www/html/archive/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

But it is not running automatically. I have waited more than a minute but it is still not running. What am I doing wrong?

And where is the main machine cron saved? The one that runs every minute and calls artisan schedule:run?

Comment: cron jobs are linux/unix OS based functionality. As far as i know, it wont work on windows, if you are trying.

Comment: I haven't booted up my windows machine in ages. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for Schedules to run, you need first to add the cron job to your cron table. Run this command

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Then choose your preferred editor.

Then add the below line:

```
 * * * * * php /var/www/html/archive/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Finally in your `Kernel.php` you add the schedule:

```
$schedule->command(<artisan command>)->everyMinute();
```

The [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling) is perfectly detailing it.

Comment: Funny I thing is I did the same thing for another project but could not recall what I was missing. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Finding cron jobs:

Depending on how your linux system is set up, you can look in:

```
 - /var/spool/cron/* (user crontabs)

 - /etc/crontab (system-wide crontab)
```

also, many distros have:

```
 - /etc/cron.d/* These configurations have the same syntax as /etc/crontab

 - /etc/cron.hourly, /etc/cron.daily, /etc/cron.weekly, /etc/cron.monthly
```

These are simply directories that contain executables that are executed hourly, daily, weekly or monthly, per their directory name.

On top of that, you can have at jobs (check `/var/spool/at/*`), anacron (`/etc/anacrontab` and `/var/spool/anacron/*`) and probably others I'm forgetting.

References : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7053/how-can-get-a-list-of-all-scheduled-cron-jobs-on-my-machine